# Using Bootstrap 4 Popover with Vue and Webpack

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, webpack, vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-4

I have a Vue project started from this template: https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack

I'm using it with Bootstrap 4 installed as a standalone NPM package:

```
"dependencies": {
  ...
  "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
  "jquery": "^3.2.1",
  "popper.js": "^1.12.9",
  ...
},
```

I imported Bootstrap in main.js as the following:

```
import 'bootstrap';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

I would like to use the [Bootstrap 4 Popover](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/popovers/) component, but when I add the markup to an A tag in a template:

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="popover" title="Title" data-content="Content">Choose</a>
```

And then I call the initialization (from the console yet):

```
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
```

I receive the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).popover is not a function
>       at :1:30
>   (anonymous) @ VM30076:1

How should I use the Popover component? Where do I have to load it?

Comment: jQuery is not available to you globally. It's more a generic issue

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! It looks like I solved it with inserting the following line to the main.js (Vue app starting point): `window.$ = require('jquery');` Except that, all other module imports all _imports_, can I somehow rewrite that to match them? I'm not really into module bundling as you can see...

Comment: You can actually use Webpack to just expose jQuery to every module instead of bundling it

Comment: Why not use sth like https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue?